# Is it possible for an F-1 graduate student in US to do internship in Europe?

Tags: united-states, europe, internship, visa

I am a graduate student in US with F-1 visa. I have an internship offer from a company in France. Is it possible/feasible for me to accept this offer, or are there any rules preventing me from doing so?

Added:

I am an Indian National with F-1 visa. The internship will be for 6 months (2 terms). I am allowed to do 3 or 6 months internship in US with CPT, but I cannot find any such information regarding internship out of US.

Comment: What country are you from? I can easily take such an offer, because I am European. Would it be just over a summer? Is it long-term? All these details are needed to answer your question.

Comment: @Johanna : I am an Indian National with F-1 visa. The internship will be for 6 months (2 terms). I am allowed to do 3 or 6 months internship in US with CPT, but I cannot find any such information regarding internship out of US.

Comment: From the point of view of the US it shouldn't matter where you go for your internship- you'll be out of the US and out of F1 status for that time period.  You should talk to your international students office about taking a leave of absence from your school.  There are regulations that allow students to take a leave from school outside of the US (more often in their home country) and then return to the US on F1 status after the leave of absence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about visa and related topics and not about academia. It may be on-topic on [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The question does touch on visa related issues but it is more centered around policies of American Universities on how to deal with international internships.

Comment: You should talk to your international office. They should know the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**U.S. Immigration Law:** While doing a summer internship would be seen as compatible with still being a full-time student because of the extended American summer, if you did the 6-month internship you may have difficulty arguing that you are still a full-time, enrolled student. You need to ask your university foreign student's office for advice as to how you can retain your F-1 status.<sup>1</sup>

**French Immigration Law:** You need to clarify with the French company that you will have a valid visa status while in the EU.

**University Policy**: As with US immigration law, you need to make sure that your status in the program is not interrupted by the internship.

---

<sup>1. Note that CPT (Curricular Practical Training) does not apply as you are not applying to work within the USA. The main  concern is that your absence for 6-months is not seen as a disruption of your studies from the perspective of maintaining your F1 visa. Your international students office should be able to advise how to maintain your student status. The bonus is that you should be able to use your OPT year in its full since you did not take a CPT.</sup>